# How to filter this specific list?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-web-api, c#-4.0

I have the following interfaces.

```
public interface IProductPrices
    {
        int ProductId { get; set; }
        string ProductCode { get; set; }
        List<IProductPrice> Prices { get; set; }
    }

public interface IProductPrice
    {
        int ProductId { get; set; }
        string PriceKey { get; }
        double Price { get; set; }
        int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

**Snippet**

```
//productPrices is of type IProductPrices
//temp is of type IProductPrice
```

.

```
........
var finalPriceList = new List<ABC.Model.ProductPrice>();
foreach (var item in productPrices)
    {
        foreach (var temp in item.Prices)
        {
            var prodPrice = new ABC.Model.ProductPrice()
            {
                Price = temp.Price,
                ProductCode = temp.ProductCode
            };
            finalPriceList.Add(prodPrice);
        }
    }
.....
```

In the snippet above there is the line

```
foreach (var temp in item.Prices)
```

I would like to select from `[item.Prices]` only if  the `[PriceKey]` is equal to `"ABC"`. If `[PriceKey]=="ABC"` does not exist then I would like to select the item with the lowest `[Price]`.

How to achieve this ?

Comment: It would be nice if you provided copy/paste-able sample input, along with expected output (in your **Snippet** section).

Comment: So you're saying that `productPrices.Prices` is guaranteed to have no more than 1 item with a `PriceKey` of "ABC"? And if the `Prices` list has such an item, you want that item, otherwise the item with the lowest price?

Comment: @itsme86  yes. Correct!

Comment: `IProductPrice item = productPrices.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PriceKey == "ABC") ?? productPrices.OrderBy(p => p.Price).FirstOrDefault();` As an aside, I wish there was a way to get `Min()` to return the item instead of the value.

Comment: Also...obligatory warning to not use `double` for monetary values due to inherent accuracy issues. `decimal` is preferred.

Comment: @itsme86 I use an extension method `MinBy` that is a call to `Aggregate`.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like a curious usage of interfaces... Even if they were classes, their structure would look weird to me...

Answer (score 0):

Using an extension method I wrote for early exiting `Aggregate`, you can write a special `MinBy` variation for this problem.

Here is the `AggregateUntil` variation I used. There are also `While` variations and variations that take a seed.

```
public static T AggregateUntil<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, T, T> accumFn, Predicate<T> endFn) {
    using (var e = src.GetEnumerator()) {
        T ans = default;
        if (e.MoveNext()) {
            ans = e.Current;
            while (!endFn(ans) && e.MoveNext())
                ans = accumFn(ans, e.Current);
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Now you can create a `MinBy` variation with an early out:

```
public static T MinByUnless<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, TKey> minFn, Func<T, bool> unlessFn ) =>
    src.AggregateUntil((a, b) => (Comparer<TKey>.Default.Compare(minFn(a), minFn(b)) < 0 && !unlessFn(b)) ? a : b, a => unlessFn(a));
```

And using it is pretty easy:

```
if (item.Prices.Any()) {
    var temp = item.Prices.MinByUnless(p => p.Price, p => p.PriceKey == "ABC");
```

Answer (score 0):

From your item.Prices you could check the priceKey == "ABC" else go get the min value with the extension Min like the example.

```
var finalPriceList = new List<ProductPrice>();
        var productPrices = new List<ProductPrice>();

        foreach (var item in productPrices)
        {
            foreach (var temp in item.Prices)
            {
                if (temp.PriceKey == "ABC")
                {
                    var prodPrice = new ProductPrice()
                    {
                        Price = temp.Price,
                        ProductCode = temp.ProductCode
                    };
                    finalPriceList.Add(prodPrice);
                }
                else
                {
                    int min = item.Prices.Min(entry => entry.Price);
                    var lowestPrice = item.Prices.Where(w => w.Price == min).Single();

                    var prodPrice = new ProductPrice()
                    {
                        Price = lowestPrice.Price,
                        ProductCode = lowestPrice.ProductCode
                    };
                    finalPriceList.Add(prodPrice);
                }
            }
        }
```